# Change content when click on navigation with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, get

I would like to change the content of my list depends on what the user "clicks" in my navigation. I am new to Ajax and dont know alot of it.

I dont want the site to "reload" so only PHP is not the soulotion here.

So if someone could be nice to me and say how this work and try to solve this problem i would be happy as a fish!

This is how it looks right now, and i have edited the picture for you to get the hang of it.

[image]

Kind Regards / A man with a problem..

Comment: use jQuery ajax() simpler to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we want to use JQuery (http://api.jquery.com/) ajax handler for this.

What you need to do is create a php page which will return the new list, you could handle this through the use of filter to display the correct information. Then you want to push that list into the container.

so using jquery, first bind a click event to the link then run something like this

```
$.get("[url]?filter=some filter", function(data){
     $([the div box id]).html(data ) 
});
```

other options include returning the filtered list as json, but for simplicity lets just stick to return html.

Answer (score 0):

It seems by default you are already loading all of the categories into the list, correct? If so, there's no need (and it is bad practice) to use AJAX to retrieve content you've already delivered.  Here is what you'll want to do.

In your PHP you will want to attach a unique class to those items (using some variation of the category name is best).  In the case of multiple categories per item, attach a unique class for each category it belongs in.

On the client side, use jQuery to only show the desired items.

`jQuery( itemSelector ).not( desiredClass ).hide(); jQuery( desiredClass ).show();`

The above will hide all feed items not in the desired class, and just in case a few of the items you wanted to show were hidden we call show on the desired class as well.

You can implement this within an onClick on the buttons on the left.